# Is it possible to get a formatStyle if condition present anywhere in the row in shiny datatable

Tags: r, shiny

I know I can use conditional formatting for a datatable in shiny but it seems to be based on specifying the column. Is there a way of highlighting a row if the condition is met anywhere in the row?

Thus far I have used ([from the datatable examples](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html)):

```
library(DT)
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))


datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(
  'V6',
  target = 'row',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
)
```

but I want it to search all the columns not just V6.

Comment: Can you provide example dataset? Maybe using mtcars?

Comment: @PoGibas I've added a dataset

Comment: So you want to color all table by `V6`?

Comment: I want to colour any row that has, for example, more than 1 in any column

Answer (score 1):

You could define an additional dummy column that is used to style the rows:

```r
library(DT)

## add style column
df$styleCol <- apply(df, 1, function(x) as.numeric(any(x >= 1)))

## highlight rows in yellow if any column >= 1
datatable(df, options = list(
            columnDefs = list(list(targets = 6, visible = FALSE))
        )) %>% formatStyle(
        "styleCol",
        target = "row",
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c("gray", "yellow"))
    )
```

[image]
**Data**

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10)))
```